# One s complement and two´s complement logic behind

Tags: binary, complement

for my computer science class I need to finish a project where I desperately need to understand logic of one´s complement and two´s complement. I already know how to construct these and also how hardware adder works when dealing with two´s complement. The thing that is bothering me and I need help with is the logic behind one´s complement addition. Why do we have to add the bit we would carry over (and discard when using two complement coding) to the sum to get the correct result? I don´t understand why binary addition behaves like this when adding one´s complement and why is that last adding of carry over bit so crucial. I need to understand the logic behind it. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might consider asking your question over at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ as this site is for programming questions.

Comment: ok, thanks, sorry for my mistake

Comment: This question belongs to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

A 1's complement number (say,16 bits) can be described as below - in terms of the relationship between the binary code *c* (which is 0..0xFFFF, or 0..65535) and the 'value' *x* which the code represents, *x* is in range -32767.. 32767.

- if the value *x* is 0..32767,  the code *c* is numerically equal to x, and thus has a zero in the MSB
- if the value *x* is negative, -1 .. -32767, then *c* is 65535 - *x*, and the MSB of *c* is 1.
- The code *c*=65535 = 0xFFFF is to be interpreted as zero; since it has a 1 in the MSB I will call it '-0'.

Now consider what happens to the *x* values when you add two codes using a a binary adder:

- If both *x1*, *x2* are positive, the adder adds the codes: *c* = *c1* + *c2*. both MSBs are zero at the input, so there will be no carry. So the value of *c* will be the sum *x1*+ *x2* and this is how it will be interpreted (assuming the sum doesn't overflow into the MSB).
- If both  *x1*, *x2* are negative, then by adding *c1*+*c2* you are adding (65535+x1)+(65535+x2). There will always be a carry-out; by discarding this you end up with a binary value equal to 65534+(x1+x2). To get the code we want to represent this negative sum, i.e. 65535+(x1+x2), we need to add 1 more.
- If the signs are different, the sum of codes is 65535+(x1+x2). There may or may not be a carry-out. Since the MSBs are different, the carry-out occurs if, and only if, the MSB of the sum is zero. In the case where the true sum (x1+x2) < 0, you won't have a carry-out, and the value 65535+(x1+x2) is the proper code for (x1+x2). If the sum (x1+x2)>0, there will be a carry-out; the sum of the codes (after discarding the carry out) will be (x1+x2)-1, and thus you have to add 1 to get the proper code (x1+x2).

So, looking at all the cases, it works out that whenever a carry-out occurs, (and you effectively subtract 65536 by discarding it) you need to add 1 to get the proper code to represent the sum.

When x1+x2 = 0  -- with one <0  and the other >0  - the sum of codes will always be 65535, which is left as is and is to be interpreted as zero ("-0").

When both are zero, you have three cases:

0 + 0 = 0    Fairly simple...

-0 + -0:  codes are 0xFFFF + 0xFFFF = (carry+ 0xFFFE) = 0xFFFF after adding carry back in, interpreted as -0.

-0+ 0:  codes are 0xFFFF + 0 = 0xFFFF  (-0)

So the only case where the 1's complement sum is a 'proper' 0 is when both inputs are proper 0. All other cases adding up to zero give a '-0'.

Mathematically, you could say that 1's complement uses (c = x) mod 65535, with *c* constrained to 0...0xFFFF.  And so the addition needs to be done modulo 65535. Each time you have a carryout, you subtract 65536 (by discarding it from the top) and add 1 (by adding it at the bottom); since you subtract 65535 in the process, the modulo 65535 value is preserved.